# Why does feeding init to last not work in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, function-composition

So I'm writing a line to get the second to last element of a list. Initially my code was

```
mySLast x = last.take ((length x) - 1) x
```

Which worked up until the `last` function. Realized the my `take` business is already included in Haskell as `init` so I rewrote as

```
mySLast = last.init
```

This still doesn't work. I find this puzzling because `init::[a]->[a]` and `last::[a]->a` so they definitely should be composable morphisms in the **Hask** Category.

I tried asking Haskell what it thinks the type is and it said

```
ghci> :t last.init
last.init :: [c] -> c
ghci> last.init [3,2,4,1]

<interactive>:45:6:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> [c]’
                with actual type ‘[Integer]’
     Relevant bindings include
       it :: a -> c (bound at <interactive>:45:1)
    Possible cause: ‘init’ is applied to too many arguments
     In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘init [3, 2, 4, 1]’
     In the expression: last . init [3, 2, 4, 1]
```

Even though

```
ghci> init [3,2,4,1]
[3,2,4]
ghci> last [3,2,4]
4
```

So I must be misunderstanding something about composing functions in Haskell. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Function application binds more tightly than `(.)` so

```
last.init [3,2,4,1]
```

is being parsed as

```
last . (init [3,2,4,1])
```

you can use

```
(last . init) [3,2,4,1]
```

or

```
last . init $ [3,2,4,1]
```

Comment: Thanks Lee! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the [`$`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) between init and your list, e.g.

```
last . init $ [3,2,4,1]
            ↑ See here
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to this problem that only evaluates the (spine of the) list up to the needed element, rather than using length (which will evaluate the entire spine before walking back to the needed element):

```
takeTail n xs = go (drop n xs) xs
  where
    go (_:ys) (_:xs) = go ys xs 
    go []     xs     = xs  -- Stop and return xs when ys runs out

> head . takeTail 2 $ [1,2,3,4]
3
```

Comment: The approach the user is trying to take has this property as well. This example can be improved by giving an explicit type signature `go :: [a] -> [b] -> [b]`, clarifying that the first argument is used only for its length.

Comment: @dfeuer Not if they're calculating the length.

Comment: Yes; their "rough draft" would indeed be inefficient. The version they typed with insufficient parentheses would be fine, although not as general as yours.